# Run webmin alongside with Plesk for managing server OS?

Tags: linux, operating-system, graphical-user-interface, plesk, webmin

I'm just bit curious if it is possible to install Webmin on a Plesk system for admin purposes. Yes I know this is like break the holy grail for many sysadmins which love the prompt, but we in our company actually like using the UI for managing our Linux server tasks as it is easier and faster in our opinion, so please kindly leave out the rant about "only use the prompt" talk.

Plesk is fine for all hosting related tasks, but it does fail on the other side with managing the server OS itself.

Webmin on the other hand actually does a fairly good option at managing the server OS through UI. Also Webmin doesn´t mess around with config files either like Plesk does.

So the question is really if it is possible to run install of Webmin on a Plesk server (without messing up Plesk of course). Also Cockpit seems like an interesting alternative to Webmin (https://cockpit-project.org/), in regards to just manage the OS part which Plesk is less good at. Yes, we do use the prompt but with loads of servers using a UI is a more productive option for us.

Thanks in advance for any feedback on this..

Kind regards

Comment: Such admin panels is a topic we avoid like the plague on this site. The reasons are given by you: they tend to mess up the actual setup to an degree that makes it hard to touch by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not advised to run Webmin or another similar software along with Plesk or other panels. Webmin for example offers configuration support for many services that should only be maintained by Plesk, e.g have configuration files generated by Plesk. Changes done manually will be overwritten when the settings are configured through Plesk GUI. There are also only a very few cases where you need to do stuff on the console when you have Plesk, so that won't be worth the trouble to have a second "panel".

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your valuable feedback.